# How to know which storage engine is used in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, storage-engines, database, nosql

Starting from version 3.0, mongodb support pluggable storage engine. How to know which storage engine is being used in a system?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Easiest way to find the storage engine being used currently in from mongo console.

Inside mongo console, type (You might need admin access to run this command)

```
db.serverStatus().storageEngine
```

If It returns,

```
{ "name" : "wiredTiger" }
```

WireTiger Storage engine is being used.

Once it is confirmed that wiredTiger is being used then type

```
db.serverStatus().wiredTiger
```

to get all the configuration details of wiredTiger.

Comment: He is the most mysterious user which I've ever seen on stackoverflow. He looks like a scholar of MongoDB. There are a lot of answer  belongs to him on stackoverflow. Also his reputation seems just 1 and account is ` temporarily suspended` every time.

Answer (score 11):

On the console, Mayank's answer makes more sense. 
On the other hand, by using MongoDB GUI like [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/) or [Robomongo](http://app.robomongo.org/download.html) storageEngine may be found by using the ways below;

On `Robomongo`;

[image]

---

On `MongoChef`;

[image]

Comment: do you know how to change the storage engine to wiredtigeR?

Comment: Yep. I've changed my storage engine by re-installing MongoDB. Check this question and answers; http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104583/61836

Answer (score 2):

You can detect this via:

```js
db.serverStatus().wiredTiger
```

So at "present" where this "exists" then there is a different storage engine configured other than the default "MMAPv1" where "WiredTiger" is not used.

This applies to the present "MongoDB 3.0x" series